# Showing part of ImageView offscreen until rotated?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show only part of my imageview on the screen.. Right now it is relative layout bottom right.. The blue circle in the first screenshot below..

The blue circle will become an 'expandable' menu button / drawer. the way I want to do it is to only show the top left quadrant of the circle, and then rotate it when someone touches the blue area, which will show the other half of the circle (which I will add buttons on top of).

The first screenshot is what I have now, the second screenshot shows how I want to push most of the circle offscreen.

Is this supported?

[image: What I have now, but I want the center of the circle at the very bottom right pixel of my layout, not the corner of the circle.. I want most of the circle actually off screen at first.]

[image]

Comment: by the way, I have seen reference code for Animating the circle itself, and I have programmatically added buttons before. The main part i'm stuck on today is how to push the center of the imageview (my blue circle) all the way to the very bottom right corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this supported?

Yes, you can use negative margin:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```